# Rsync Over SSH without PWD as Root -Catch-22

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync, sftp

I have a remote directory that I want to rsync to my local machine over a ssh without a password because I want it be run as a cronjob (root user)

This command (no `sudo`) fails because it cannot write files to `/var/www/html/test-sftp`

```
rsync -avz -e ssh --progress user@888.888.888.88:~/public_html/test-sftp/ /var/www/html/test-sftp
```

Whereas this command (has `sudo`) but will fail because the remote server requests a password to access `user@888.888.888.88:~/public_html/test-sftp/`

And NOTE: I can log in with `ssh -p 2222 user@888.888.888.88` WITHOUT a password.

Question:  In my crontab, if I specify *`My-user_name`* instead of `root`, would the `rsync` execute properly?

Scratching my head... any thoughts?

Comment: I can ssh connect to remote server without using a password.  if I use ssh -p 2222 user@888.888.888.88  on the command line.  But, when I use the rsync command above, the remote server requests a login password for the server...

Comment: You're controlling the copy on your local machine, running the task as root, which is to copy files from the remote to local? And using this local root user account you can successfully `ssh -p 2222 user@888.888.888.88 id` and get an answer without needing a password?

Answer (score 0):

#### Analysis

If you run `rsync` as My-user_name from the crontab, it will behave like `rsync` run without `sudo`. Even if you give the user write access to the destination directory, problems will arise because non-root cannot fully benefit from `-a` (e.g. `rsync -a` will not be able to preserve ownership, it won't even try).

You need to run `rsync` as root. Then with `-e ssh` it will run `ssh` as root. When you say "I can log in without a password", I guess you have a key and `ssh` running as My-user_name finds and uses the key automatically. Now the problem is `ssh` running as root does not find this key automatically.

---

#### Solutions

Fortunately what you pass to `rsync -e` is a *full command*, not just a name of some executable. Instead of sole `ssh` you can pass `ssh -i /path/to/the/key` where `/path/to/the/key` is `/home/My-user_name/.ssh/id_rsa` or so. You just need to quote right, so the entire command forms a single option-argument to `-e`. It would be like

```
sudo rsync -avz -e 'ssh -i /home/My-user_name/.ssh/id_rsa' …
```

`ssh` running as root [should be able to read the file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/117150/108618).

Alternatively (and I would prefer this solution) you can `sudo -u My-user_name ssh`, so `ssh` itself runs as My-user_name and finds your key automatically. `rsync` running as root should be able to run commands with `sudo` as any user without a password. The full command is

```
sudo rsync -avz -e 'sudo -u My-user_name ssh' …
```

---

#### In crontab

In a crontab you may not need the first `sudo`.

- In the system-wide crontab you don't need the first `sudo`, just specify root as the user.
- In root's crontab ([which is not the system-wide one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/127734/108618)) you don't need the first `sudo`, `rsync` will be run as root because it's the root's crontab.
- In your crontab you need the first `sudo`, then you need the command to work without password. [It's possible](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43139/108618), but if I were you I would use the system-wide or root's crontab in the first place.

Keep in mind [cron uses `PATH`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/401621/108618) that is not your `PATH`; `sudo` can use [yet another `PATH`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/83191/108618). If you're not sure `rsync` (or any other executable) is in the `PATH` that matters at the moment then consider using its full path.

When the time comes, cron will run the job [regardless if the previous one finished](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14984650/10765659), and [you don't want to run multiple `rsync`s](https://serverfault.com/q/332577). I would use [`flock`](https://serverfault.com/a/82863) to prevent the situation.

Answer (score 0):

The following command which is a modified version of @Bulat's answer on  [Using rsync with sudo on the destination machine](https://askubuntu.com/a/1155897/119371) worked for me.

```
read -s -p "Remote sudo password: " SUDOPASS && sudo --preserve-env=SUDOPASS rsync -avz --stats --rsync-path="echo -n $SUDOPASS | sudo -Sv && sudo rsync" remoteuser@remotehost:/src/ /destination/
```

ZSH does not support the `-p` option for `read`. Instead you should use

```
read -s "SUDOPASS?Remote sudo password: " && sudo --preserve-env=SUDOPASS rsync -avz --stats --rsync-path="echo -n $SUDOPASS | sudo -Sv && sudo rsync" remoteuser@remotehost:/src/ /destination/
```

The command did not work for me on macOS.